# Do not allow same value in different columns for the same record in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I am building a website in django that will allow players to be matched with other players. I have the following model:

```
class Session(models.Model):
    # id = AutoField(primary_key=True) added automatically.
    sport = models.ForeignKey('Sport', unique=False, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    hostplayer = models.ForeignKey('Member', unique=False, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='member_host', )
    guestplayer = models.ForeignKey('Member', unique=False, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='member_guest', )
    date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False, )
    time = models.TimeField(blank=False, null=False, )
    city = models.ForeignKey('City', unique=False, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE, )
    location = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=False, blank=False, null=False, )
    price = models.FloatField(unique=False, blank=False, null=False, default=0, )
    details = models.TextField(unique=False, blank=True, null=False, )

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.id)
```

As you can see, both hostplayer and guestplayer are foreign keys of the Member table.

The problem is that when I go into django admin, if I select the hostplayer as `jack`, I can also select the guestplayer as `jack`. This is obviously wrong as a player cannot play against himself.

**How can I limit the options of `guestplayer` to not include the `hostplayer`?**

Also, on the models level, **is there a way to specify that the value of one attribute must be different from the value of another attribute in the same tuple?** An obvious way would be to use forms and validate them but I am curious whether a simpler alternative exists.

Comment: Hey , I came across same issue , Did u found out how to solve this ?

Comment: In the end I discussed this with my lecturer. His basic take on this was that it can be done but it's not worth the hassle. I can't remember specifically what he said the steps were as this was a few months back but at the time I agreed with him...